# Filter using a for loop and return multiple data frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a df that looks like that:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| Fruit  |    Date    | Sales |
+--------+------------+-------+
| Apple  | 01/01/2020 |    20 |
| Apple  | 01/02/2020 |    30 |
| Orange | 01/01/2019 |    55 |
| Orange | 01/02/2018 |    15 |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

I want to create a loop that will filter the df by the fruit and then create multiple df, one for each fruit. O the example, my goal is to have the following two separate df:

```
Apple:
+--------+------------+-------+
| Fruit  |    Date    | Sales |
+--------+------------+-------+
| Apple  | 01/01/2020 |    20 |
| Apple  | 01/02/2020 |    30 |
+--------+------------+-------+
Orange:
+--------+------------+-------+
| Fruit  |    Date    | Sales |
+--------+------------+-------+
| Orange | 01/01/2020 |    55 |
| Orange | 01/02/2020 |    15 |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

I've tried the code:

```
# list of fruits
fruits= df['Fruits'].unique()

for fruit in fruits:
  fruit= pd.DataFrame()
  fruit= df[df['Fruit']==fruit].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Probably I need to create first a list and then convert to a df, but I'm quite confused, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are trying to create multiple dataframe names as same as the unique fruit names.

The below code snippet will not work as the variable `fruit` is being replaced as `pd.DataFrame()` and will not be "Apple" or "Orange"

```
for fruit in fruits:
  fruit = pd.DataFrame() # fruit will not be anymore Apple or Orange
  fruit = df[df['Fruit']==fruit].reset_index(drop=True)
```

There are two ways to create the dataframes as required

1. Using `exec()` method (Not recommended much)

```
fruits = df['Fruit'].unique()

for fruit in fruits:
    # To use the fruit as variable name put it in {} and as the direct value use it straight

    exec(f"{fruit} = df[df['Fruit']==fruit].reset_index(drop=True)")

print(Orange)

Fruit   Date        Sales
Orange  01/01/2019  55
Orange  01/02/2018  15


print(Apple)

Fruit   Date        Sales
Apple   01/01/2020  20
Apple   01/02/2020  30
```

2. Create Class to store dynamic variable as object and retrieve it from class later

```
class df_names:
    pass

fruit_df = df_names()  #fruit_df will now hold all the variables that we are going to create


fruits = df['Fruit'].unique()

for fruit in fruits:

    # To use the fruit as variable name put it in {} and as the direct value use it straight
    # setattr(variable_holder, variable_name, value)
    setattr(fruit_df, f"{fruit}", df[df['Fruit']==fruit].reset_index(drop=True))


for fruit in fruits:
    print(getattr(fruit_df, f"{fruit}"))


Fruit  Date           Sales
Apple  01/01/2020     20
Apple  01/02/2020     30

Fruit   Date          Sales
Orange  01/01/2019     55
Orange  01/02/2018     15
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly for me, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('Fruit')
```

does exactly that!  It also has the added benefit that it is multithreaded so it is still fast to do further operations on, AND you can still keep all the data in one place so you are not copying it when the input data gets big!